# Water puddle in backyard causing leaking in garage concrete wall

Tags: concrete, leak, garage, waterproofing, gutters

This is what I saw in the backyard of a split level home after a light rain

[image]

The water was there due to overflow from gutter. I can clean the gutter but the puddle situation must be fixed as it will come back in some other way. The left side is concrete wall and here are photos of the other side which is the garage

[image]

Obviously someone tried to fix the leak by patching the crack with cement

[image]

I am not sure if this method works or not as I have not lived here for a full year yet to know.

Questions:

1. What to do about the water puddle problem? Should I dig a trend somewhere and how to create that structure?
2. If the leak is still there in the garage, what do I do about the crack? Any better way to fix the leak?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as the puddle is concerned, if you could you dig a trench from the puddle under the wooden gate, would that conduct the water away from the house? Then fill the trench with large gravel so it conducts water but can be walked on.

Comment: The gutter is falling off the house. Cleaning it out won’t fix it       it needs to be reattached and pitched toward downspout. Downspout outflow needs to be directed away from house